# error when displaying toast

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to run a toast in sequence in order to display a ruuning rss feed. I am getting the following error when running:java.lang.RuntimeException: This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()

My code is:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastimage);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bball_icon);
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setView(layout);
for (int i=0;i<episode_titles.size();i++)
{
    toast.setText(episode_titles.get(i).toString());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat from your error?

Comment: 02-28 11:11:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9715): java.lang.RuntimeException: This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()

Comment: Actually we need the logcat that refers to the actual error, you mentioned running:java.lang.RuntimeException!

Comment: at android.widget.Toast.setText(Toast 272)

Comment: Can you post the code where you create episode_titles?

Comment: have you gone through links for how to make custom toast? http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-customize-toasts

Comment: can you please elaborate on your requirement, i mean what exactly you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: I want to display the rss feed in toasts that will appear one after each other

Comment: I think your problem is when you are using .toString(), what are you trying to convert to string?

Comment: true I dont need toString() but I am getting the same error still...

Comment: please refer to my answer user1163234

Answer (score 24):

To set text to toast, you have to initialize it via `makeText`.

Like this:

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setText("new message");
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    //other setters
    toast.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only call *toast.SetText()* if you have previously created the toast using one of the *makeText* methods. See the documentation of the method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setView(android.view.View)

In your example, you should update the text using the *TextView* rather than the *Toast*

Comment: tried this: "text.setText(episode_titles.get(i).toString());" but only got the last result of episode_titles

Answer (score 2):

The Toast U can specify like this...

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Then u can write like this...

```
       String s=episode_titles.get(i).toString();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UrMessage:"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
for (int i=0;i<episode_titles.size();i++)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), episode_titles.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Its works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `toast.setText(episode_titles.get(i).toString());`, use 
`text.setText();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastimage);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bball_icon);
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setView(layout);
for (int i=0;i<episode_titles.size();i++)
{
    text.setText(episode_titles.get(i).toString());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    toast.show();

}
```

Let me know if this works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
//your for loop here    {   
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        TextView txt1 =  new TextView(this);
        txt1.setText(R.string.hello);
        toast.setView(txt1);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible to add text directly,

Comment: @Andhrudu Yes, it is. Look at my reply.

Answer (score 0):

To set text to toast , you have to use makeText.

Like this:

```
Toast toast =  Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.noSearchMatch ) , LENGTH_SHORT );
      toast.setGravity ( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0 , 0);
      toast.show ( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a android Emulator to run you app? find your emulator if support x86```

Comment: There might be an answer hidden in here (and there should be one or this would be flaggable for not being an answer), but the phrasing is so hard to parse that I get more of  an impression that you are asking a clarification question, for which a comment should be used, which you do not yet have the privilege for. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Then rephrase this more cleary as an answer - or delete this right away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).